# mysql получить максимальное значение

Tags: mysql

Нужно получить максимальное значение из 100 строк для каждой 10 строчки, т.е. 10 максимальных значений. Подскажите, как организовать подобную выборку?

Comment: Сделайте select с обратным порядком по значению нужного поля и возьмите первый 10 строк через limit 10.

Comment: @Visman, так надо "для каждой 10 строчки", а ваш вариант вернет только последнюю 10ку

Comment: Вы правы, нужно для "каждой 10-й из лимита 100 строк"

Comment: Тогда пусть автор покажет свой вариант и что у него в нем не работает :) И как интересно можно получить максимум " для каждой 10 строчки"? Для каждых десяти строк - можно, для каждой десятой - нет!

Comment: А по какому признаку строчки группировать? Если есть поле id и оно непрерывно (т.е. нет такого, что есть id=N-1, есть id=N+1, но нет id=N), то можно сделать группировку вида `GROUP BY ROUND(id/10)`, но мне, если честно, такой вариант не нравится

Comment: SELECT pid, min(time) AS min_pid, MAX(time) AS max_pid FROM entries WHERE pid = tid  GROUP BY ROUND(pid/5) LIMIT 10 , как задать лимит, чтобы сгруппировались 5 записей из установленных 10? нужна в общем пагинация, чтобы можно было выбрать от куда и до можно групировать